# How To Interpret Share Prices?

Tags: financial-literacy, shares, stock-valuation, google-finance

During conversation shares in Google came up as a topic. Out of interest I Googled the share price for Google and was presented the following:

> Google Inc. (GOOG) -NasdaqGS
>
> 523.40

My question is how to interpret this?

Does this translate as £/$ 523 per share, or some other unit of measurement? The raw number, without the right knowledge, allows for comparison but not a real interpretation of the values.

Comment: Without meaning to offend anyone, but can I have a reason for downvotes? I don't mind getting them, but for the good of the network it is good practice to share criticism so the perpetrator can improve in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing information is at the end of the first line: the price is from NASDAQ (most specifically [Nasdaq Global Select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASDAQ#Market_tiers)), which is a stock exchange in the USA, so the price is in US Dollars.

Comment: So in this example, the buying/selling price per share is $523.40? So the local Stock Exchange number relates to the local currency? I.E. FTSE is £

Comment: @nickson104: correct.

Comment: While in general this rule-of-thumb is correct, there are exceptions. Here in Canada, for instance, it is possible for shares to be quoted simultaneously in Canadian dollars as well as U.S. dollars. e.g. the Royal Canadian Mint's Canadian Gold Reserves receipts are quoted in both CAD and USD.

Comment: @nickson104 yes in general, but there are caveats - in that particular case, UK prices are usually quoted in pence, not pounds, so 523 there would indicate £5.23.